# replace content string with nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

I use [this content](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/subhanahmet/lorem/main/loram.js) in my subdomain: https://sub.highping.com.tr/lorem

I want replace all **"ipsum"** strings when nginx_proxy process.

Can I do it whith **ngx_http_sub_module** ?

So I tried but couldn't do it.

```
location  /lorem {

proxy_pass https://raw.githubusercontent.com/subhanahmet/lorem/main/loram.js;

sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter_types text/html;
sub_filter "ipsum" "sometext";
sub_filter_once on;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that your `loram.js` file is not served as **"text/html"** Content-Type.

```
location /lorem {
    proxy_pass https://raw.githubusercontent.com/subhanahmet/lorem/main/loram.js;

    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    sub_filter_types text/html;

    sub_filter 'ipsum' 'sometext';
    sub_filter_once off;
}
```

After updating the configuration, make sure you restart nginx.

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks for help. But after changing some things it worked. Like that:

proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

sub_filter 'ipsum' 'sometext';
sub_filter_once off;
sub_filter_types text/html text/plain text/css text/js text/xml
   text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json 
   application/xml;

Comment: You are most welcome! 
You can mention on **nginx** related problems. And I will try to fix them!

Comment: Kayes I try [Clickup Docs](https://doc.clickup.com/31186101/p/h/xqq5n-104/739a5a0867b76cb) with proxy_pass but it does not working.